# presentModalViewController crash while sending email on 3G

Tags: iphone, email, ios5, 3g, presentmodalviewcontroller

I am trying to send the device log file via email and using the below code. I am able to send the email in iPod Touch and iPad in wi-fi network. But when  I am trying to send the email in iPhone on 3G network there is crash. I debuted the code and came to know that this is crashing while doing presentModalViewController.

Please help me ,how to resolve this issue.

```
- (IBAction)sendEmail:(id)sender
{
  MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
  picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;
 
  // Set the subject of email
  [picker setSubject:@"Debug Log"];
 
  // Add email addresses
  [picker setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"emailaddress1@domainName.com", @"emailaddress2@domainName.com", nil]];
 
  // Fill out the email body text
  NSString *emailBody = @"Debug Log content…… ";
 
  // This is not an HTML formatted email
  [picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];
 
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,    
NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *logPath = [documentsDirectory   
stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"console.log"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:logPath];
  [picker addAttachmentData:data mimeType:@"text/xml" fileName:@"console.log"];
 
  // Show email view    
  [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];//app crash
 
  // Release picker
  [picker release];
}
 
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error 
{
  // Called once the email is sent
  // Remove the email view controller   
  [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before sending mail check that email is configured in the iOS device.

You can check the capability for sending mail through code before sending mail as below.

```
- (IBAction)sendEmail:(id)sender
{
  MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
  picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;
 
  // Set the subject of email
  [picker setSubject:@"Debug Log"];
 
  // Add email addresses
  [picker setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"emailaddress1@domainName.com", @"emailaddress2@domainName.com", nil]];
 
  // Fill out the email body text
  NSString *emailBody = @"Debug Log content…… ";
 
  // This is not an HTML formatted email
  [picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];
 
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,    
NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *logPath = [documentsDirectory   
stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"console.log"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:logPath];

  [picker addAttachmentData:data mimeType:@"text/xml" fileName:@"console.log"];
 
  // Show email view    
 Class mailClass = (NSClassFromString(@"MFMailComposeViewController"));
  if (mailClass != nil) {
    // We must always check whether the current device is configured for sending emails
    if ([mailClass canSendMail]) {
      [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
    } else {
      //do something
    }
  } else {
   //do something
  } 
  // Release picker
  [picker release];
}

- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error 
{
  // Called once the email is sent
  // Remove the email view controller   
  [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is to encapsulate your call to the `presentModalViewController` with this code snippet:

```
Class mailClass = (NSClassFromString(@"MFMailComposeViewController"));
if (mailClass != nil)
{ 
    if ([mailClass canSendMail])
    {
        [self presentModalViewController:YOURMAILCOMPOSER animated:YES];
    }
}
```

This will even give you an automatically generated alert view for your user telling them to set up mail accounts before continuing...